# qml does not accept keyboard event until i switch windows

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I am developing some kind of a video player in QML. I want to control it by Keyboard events but the problem is that the qml doesn't seem to accept any keyboard event until I switch the window and comeback to the app window. I tried with
"focus: true"
"enabled : true"

and
"FocusScope: Item"

but nothing worked for me

Comment: I see this too when I run from Qt Creator. But if I directly run the app from a console it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by tracing the focus. The problem was during the frame/page switches I lost the focus. Hence I enabled it on each frame by [forceActiveFocus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#forceActiveFocus-method-1).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Shortcut` you should disable the shortcuts in your parent pages.

**main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow 
{
    id:mainWindow

    Shortcut {
        id:backShortcut
        sequences: ["Esc", "Back"]

        onActivated: {
            console.log("Back Shortcut In main Page")
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomPage.qml**

````
Page{

    Component.onCompleted: {
        backShortcut.enabled=false
    }
    Component.onDestruction: {
        backShortcut.enabled=true
    }
    Shortcut {
        id:backShortcutCustomPage
        sequences: ["Esc", "Back"]
        onActivated: {
            console.log("Back Shortcut In Custom Page")
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: I am not using shortcuts, rather I preferred to use _Keys.onPressed: {console.log("KEY PRESSED")}_ Method.

The problem is that when I press a key it prints nothing and whenever I switch my screen to some other application and back to my app, it works perfect

Comment: I tried to print the [activeFocus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#activeFocus-prop) property it prints _false_
and when after switching the window it prints _true_

i want to know how do I manually set the value of it to tru?